# SQL Insert if not exist with where class

Tags: mysql

in the below table which is in the name of TBL_TEST1 I want that if the record exists and it matched with my where class then it should not be inserted and if the record does not match with my where class then it should insert that. 
i am using Mysql

Example:

```
IF NOT EXIST (SELECT ID FROM TBL_TEST1 WHERE ID = 1 AND GM = 'Yes') INSERT INTO TBL_TEST1 (ID, GM) VALUES ('1','Yes')
```

[image: Example]

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: the question is how to insert data if that not matched the data in it

Comment: And what exactly is the problem? Is the SQL code you provided throwing an error? Producing the wrong result?

Comment: this is the error code ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

Answer (score 0):

As you've seen, you can't use procedural constructs like this out of the blue in Oracle.

One neat(?) trick you could use is select the value you mean to insert and remove the values present in the table from it:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_test1 (id, gm)
SELECT 1, 'YES' FROM dual
MINUS
SELECT id, gm FROM tbl_test1 WHERE id = 1 AND gm = 'YES'
```